# How can i delete values from an array using .filter()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a leaderboard for a game. The userInfo array that i am using contains fetched data from a json table. The array contains `id`, `username`, `bestattempts` and `besttime` along with the data from each category.

This table currently have 4 columns and all the data from the json table is on table rows. I need to have the table not showing the data of the users that have `bestattemps < 5` or `besttime === 0`. I'm trying to filter the data from the array but it's not working and i am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` on this line `const keys = Object.keys(newArray[0])`

Here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./LeaderBoard.css";


const Head = ({keys, head}) => {
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>
    {
      keys.map(key =><th key={key}>{head[key] || key}</th> )
    }
    </tr>
  </thead>

  )
}
const Row = ({row}) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(row)

  return (

  <tr key={row.Rank}>
    {
      keys.map(key => <td key={key}>{row[key]}</td>)

    }

 </tr> )
}
  const LeaderBoard = ({usersInfo, head}) => {

    usersInfo.sort(function sortByAttempts(a, b) {
      if(a.bestattempts !== b.bestattempts){
        return a.bestattempts - b.bestattempts
      }else{
        return a.besttime - b.besttime
      }

  });

const newArray = usersInfo.map(({ id, ...rest }, index) => ({ Rank: index + 1, ...rest }) )

  const keys = Object.keys(newArray[0])

  const filteredData = newArray.filter(usersInfo => usersInfo.bestattempts >= 5 && usersInfo.besttime !== 0);



  return (
  <div className="Leaderboard-wrapper">
  <table>
    <Head keys={keys} head={head}/>
    <tbody>
      {
        filteredData.map((row) => <Row row={row}/>)
      }
    </tbody>
  </table></div>
)
};

export default LeaderBoard;
```

On app.js as a prop

```
 const head = {
                id: "ID",
                username: "Username",
                bestattempts: "Best Attempts",
                besttime: "Best Time",
            }
```

Comment: Can you create a simple example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: `filteredData` array is empty. So, `Object.keys(undefined)` is throwing the error

Comment: You also should change the name of the parameter in the `filter` callback to be different from the array itself. Currently, both are `usersInfo`

Comment: @adiga how do i fix that? isn't that suppose to have the usersInfo array filtered in there?

Comment: Are there any items in the `usersInfo` which satisify the condition?

Comment: If you are certain that `usersInfo` will always have data but `filteredData` won't, you can do the `map` first, get the keys of `0` index and `filter` after that. Just add check for array length > 0 before doing `Object.keys()` just in case `usersInfo` array comes as empty

Comment: Updated the code to match what you said. Can you take a look? Getting the list of usersInfo, but it's not filtered (Users with bestattemps <5 and besttime = 0 are still appearing)

Comment: @adiga, how do i do the check?

Comment: Couple of changes: 1) Should be `newArray.filter` not `keys.filter` 2) `filteredData.map(row => <Row )` and not `newArray.map(row => <Row)`

Comment: @adiga yap i noticed that. Still not working. Now i just have the head of the table working. The data on body is not showing.

Comment: You need to debug this. Add breakpoints and `console.log(filteredData )` and check if there are any data for the condition

Comment: Ok. Nevermind, is working fine. I had a problem on the json file, no data had a bestattempt > 5. Really really sorry for taking your time. And thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to hardcode the headers. Instead of relying on the data from filter which can result with empty array and hence `array[0]` throws, think about hardcoding your headers. Small change such as `const keys = ['Rank', 'username', 'bestattempts', 'besttime'].`

Besides eventually you will want the header values not to be dependent on keys describing your objects. I would also recommend changing the implementation of Row and instead of doing a loop in all keys, decide the order in which you want to return them. Something like

```
<td>{row['Rank']}</td>
<td>{row['username']}</td>
<td>{row['bestattempts']}</td>
<td>{row['besttime']}</td>
```

This way you have full control of the ordering of the values.